# Raw SQL in order by in django model query

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I've a simple query like this (*I want 1 BHK to come first, then 2BHK, then anything else*)

```
select *
from service_options
order by case space when '1BHK' then 0 when '2BHK' then 1 else 2 end,
         space
```

In Django, how to do it? I've a model named `ServiceOption`

I tried this but no luck.

```
ServiceOption.objects.order_by(RawSQL("case space when '1BHK' then 0 when '2BHK' then 1 else 2 end,space"), ()).all()
```

I don't want to execute raw query with something like

```
ServiceOption.objects.raw("raw query here")
```

In **Laravel**, something like this could easily be pulled off like this

```
Model::query()->orderByRaw('raw order by query here')->get();
```

Any input will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work with a [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) and then [**`.order_by(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by):

```
from django.db.models import Case, IntegerField, Value, When

ServiceOption.objects.annotate(
    sp=Case(
        When(space='1BHK', then=Value(0)),
        When(space='2BHK', then=Value(1)),
        default=Value(2),
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )
).order_by('sp', 'space')
```

The raw query would come to this

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN "service_options"."space" = 1BHK THEN 0 WHEN "service_options"."space" = 2BHK THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS "sp" FROM "service_options" ORDER BY "sp" ASC, "service_options"."space" ASC
```

Since [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2) you can work with [**`.alias(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#alias) to prevent calculating this both as column and in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
from django.db.models import Case, IntegerField, Value, When

ServiceOption.objects.alias(
    sp=Case(
        When(space='1BHK', then=Value(0)),
        When(space='2BHK', then=Value(1)),
        default=Value(2),
        output_field=IntegerField()
    )
).order_by('sp', 'space')
```

The raw query would come to this

```
SELECT * FROM "service_options" ORDER BY CASE WHEN ("service_options"."space" = 1BHK) THEN 0 WHEN ("service_options"."space" = 2BHK) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC, "service_options"."space" ASC
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the solution. However, is there any way to execute a raw query just for the order by? In laravel, I could easily do it with something like $query->orderByRaw('raw order by query here').

Comment: The actual query executed for your answer would translate to
`select *, case space when '1BHK' then 0 when '2BHK' then 1 else 2 end as sp from service_options order by sp, space` However, that's completely different from the raw query that I suggested in the question.

Comment: @KoushikDas: no, if you do this with `.annotate`, then it will both use `sp` in the `SELECT` and the `ORDER BY` clause, if you make use of `.alias(...)` it will only use the `CASE ...` in the `ORDER BY` where it is necessary.